# How to play a song from the itunes library in iphone

Tags: iphone, ipod

Hi i need to play a song from the itunes library. I had gone through the Apples ipod Library Access Guide and got the code.

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
MPMediaItem *song;
for (song in itemsFromGenericQuery) 
{
    NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
}

//assign a playback queue containing all media items on the device
[myPlayer setQueueWithQuery:everything];//setQueueWithQuery:everything];

//start playing from the begining
[myPlayer play];
```

But This will start playing from the very beginning of the library list. I need to play a song when i select it from the list. Can anyone help me please...

Thanks,
Shibin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `MPMediaPickerController` instance you can choose from the iPod library's song list, album list, etc.. Here is an example which selects all the songs from the iPod and displays in a modal view controller.

```
- (IBAction) selectSong: (id) sender 
{   
    MPMediaPickerController *picker =
    [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

    picker.delegate                     = self;
    picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems   = NO;
    picker.prompt                       = NSLocalizedString (@"Select any song from the list", @"Prompt to user to choose some songs to play");

    [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];
    [picker release]; 
}
```

Now you need to implement the delegate to store the song into your local variable. Here, `selectedSongCollection` is an instance of `MPMediaItemCollection`.

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    selectedSongCollection=mediaItemCollection; 
}
```

After you are done with selecting the song, implement the delegate to dismiss the picker:

```
- (void) mediaPickerDidCancel: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker 
{   
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES]; 
}
```

Comment: @crazyoxygen: As i have already mentioned in the answer, selectedSongCollection is an instance of MPMediaItemCollection.

Comment: Can I combine this with local Notification sound ??

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning a playlist of all songs to the music player, so of course it is going to play the entire list, starting at the beginning. If you want the user to select a specific song from the iPod library, use `MPMediaPickerController`.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't use the`MPMediaPickerController` in my scenario.

My short answer to question is to have a look at `[musicplayer setNowPlayingItem:item]`

here's some code below from my implementation.

```
// Create a new query
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *mpp = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"a" forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];
[query addFilterPredicate:mpp]; 

// Retrieve the results and reload the table data
DATAENV.songCollections = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:query.collections];

//populate cell rows with 

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPMediaItem *item = [[[DATAENV.songCollections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] items] lastObject];
    titleLbl = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MPMediaItem *item = [[[self.songCollections objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] items] lastObject];
    [PLAYER setNowPlayingItem:item];
    [PLAYER play];
}
```

Where PLAYER/ DATAENV are my singletons

```
#define PLAYER  [[AudioController sharedAudioController_instance] musicPlayer]
#define DATAENV [DataEnvironment sharedDataEnvironment_instance]
```