# How to start and stop songs programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to play a song from the itunes library in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone)

In my app,

I want to fetch songs from iPhone Library.

And want to play that song.

How do I fetch song?

And How to start and stop songs programmatically in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recordFile] error:nil];
            [player prepareToPlay];
   [player play];

    [player pause];
```