# itunes library implement in ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, itunes

I'm working on an application in which i am not able to access the iPod videos in my app.so I'm thinking about integrating the iTunes.so that i can be able to download the videos from iTunes store and store it to local directory and from that directory i can be able to play the videos.

I can play the videos from  photo gallery in popOverController but not be able to play it in

```
-(IBAction)SelectVideo:(id)sender
   {

       UIImagePickerController *ImageVideoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
       ImageVideoPicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
       ImageVideoPicker.delegate = self;
           [ImageVideoPicker setMediaTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie, nil]];

  /////////videoLibrary is PopOver to show Videos Of photo gallery////////  
            VideoLibrary= [[UIPopoverController alloc]
               initWithContentViewController:ImageVideoPicker];
          [VideoLibrary presentPopoverFromRect:addVideo.frame inView:self.videoView   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////function did select the video//////////////////

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
 {

        NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
        if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){

    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    UIAlertView *alurl=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"message"    message:videoURL delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:@"cancel", nil];
            [alurl show];
            [alurl release];
  //////////////this url is used to play video in
 app.VideoUrl=videoURL;          
     NSLog(@"%@",app.VideoUrl);

}
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

i am not be able to play from this app.videoUrl.So if anyone had done Itunes Store integration then please point me to the right direction.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually want the MPMediaPickerController with the mediaTypes property set to the appropriate bitwise mask:

```
// video media types
MPMediaTypeMovie        = 1 << 8,
MPMediaTypeTVShow       = 1 << 9,
MPMediaTypeVideoPodcast = 1 << 10,
MPMediaTypeMusicVideo   = 1 << 11,
MPMediaTypeVideoITunesU = 1 << 12,
MPMediaTypeAnyVideo     = 0xff00,

// generic media type
MPMediaTypeAny          = ~0
```

Comment: There's a similar SO question that deals with Music, but shows a good example of using the MPMediaPickerController: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone