# read sound resource where itune has

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

is it possible to obtain the sound resource like mp3 where itune has

i think NSBundle and NSHomeDirectory show only my app's directories

is there any appropriate method existing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an MPMediaPicker controller to let the user select the MPMediaItemCollection from their library. [Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone).

You're right, your app is sandboxed from the rest of the system, so you can't access the actually files themselves, only MPMediaItem's.

Comment: Glad it worked! If you're satisfied with the answer, could you mark it as "Accepted" by clicking the checkmark?