# How can i integrate iPod Playlist(Songs) in iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ipod, mpmediapickercontroller

Really it's first time am trying to get iPod playlist songs in iPhone app. I just refereed Apple document to integrate the iPod songs (Library) into an iPhone app. Form apple document i learned we need to use 'MPMediaPickerController' to get the iPod songs library. But, i dont know how to do this in iphone app. Can anyone please help me to do this?

Comment: dude there are many code samples available on google

Comment: same link :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper thanks for your suggestion. I will use that link. Thanks a lot.