# Is it possible to remap the headset buttons

Tags: iphone

Is it possible using the SDK to change the bluetooth headset/remote buttons behavior. I would like to capture the button press(es) and perform some action, eg, skip next track, launch popup etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will receive appropriate callbacks from iOS when a button is pressed, and within these callbacks you can decide what to do.

Comment: Thank you. I found some code to receive the callbacks (link below) what i'm not sure is if it's possible to then send an event to the ipod app to tell it to skip track for example? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html

Comment: Oh, I thought you were creating a music app yourself. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone) and other questions regarding play/pause of iTunes songs.