# Pick Audio by MPMediaPickerController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mpmediapickercontroller

Hi I'm using MPMediaPickerController to picking Audio file from Phone library. but it give me blank screen. I can't understand why this is happening. I'm running app on simulator. This my code

```
- (IBAction)selectFile:(UIButton *)sender{

MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];
mediaPicker.delegate = self;
mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
mediaPicker.prompt = @"Select Your Favourite Song!";
[mediaPicker loadView];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MPMediaPickerController does not work in the Simulator**. Apple notes this in the "iPod Library Access Programming Guide" under "Hello Music Player". The note says:

> Note: To follow these steps you’ll need a provisioned device because
>   the Simulator has no access to a device’s iPod library.

To prevent the assertion you can always check if you can access the do this in your code (code bellow uses ARC and iOS SDK 5.0).

```
MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc]     initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];

[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems:YES];
[picker setPrompt:NSLocalizedString(@"Add songs to play","Prompt in media item picker")];

@try {
[picker loadView]; // Will throw an exception in iOS simulator
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@catch (NSException *exception) {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Oops!",@"Error title")
                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"The music library is not available.",@"Error message when MPMediaPickerController fails to load") 
                           delegate:nil 
                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                  otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how can I pick Audio from iTune?

Comment: do you want to play them?

Comment: Yes, it is running on device but no content here. I'm new to this platform so I don't know how can I download conten from iTune

Comment: First of all you can not download the content from due to copyrights issue, and you can only play the content! and for which you can refer to this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665119/how-to-play-a-song-from-the-itunes-library-in-iphone

Comment: Actually I want it to set as a background music of video that will recorded in this app. I want to select it from iTune and later i'll merge it with recorded video. so what I need to do?

Answer (score 3):

For those who want the answer in Swift:

```
@IBAction func openMediaPickerController(sender: AnyObject) {
        let picker = MPMediaPickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = true
        picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString("Chose audio file", comment: "Please chose an audio file")
        self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
func mediaPickerDidCancel(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
func mediaPicker(mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection) {
    //run any code you want once the user has picked their chosen audio
}
```